# How can i assign value of nsmutable array which is inside of nsmutable dictionary into another nsmutable dictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

How can i assign value of nsmutable array which is inside of nsmutable dictionary into another nsmutable dictionary or NSDictionary?

```
  NSMutableDictionary *readers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[readers setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"id"];
readers[@"publicAccess"] = @NO;



// Create dictionary of parameters to be passed with the request
NSDictionary *data = @{
     // @"reader_ids": [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",[readers[@"id"]componentsJoinedByString:@","]],

                       };

 NSDictionary *data = @{
     @"reader_ids": // i need here values of "id" as string which is separated by comma since  **reader_ids** is string property and id is MSMutable Array which contains datas.
```

I need to get value of both **id** and **publicAccess** and assign into another NSDictionary.

Comment: You explanation is not enough. you can get back the object for id and publicAccess by using objectForKey method of NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: i need to assign value of id and publicAccess property of NSMutable dictionary into another NSDicationary

Comment: use [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwitharray:YourArray]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSMutableArray *mArray = readers[@"id"];
    BOOL publicAccess = readers[@"publicAccess"];
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithBool: publicAccess];

NSString * result = [mArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]
     NSDictionary * data = @{@"readers_ids" :result,@"publicAccess" : num};
```

Comment: Why not use the new Objective-C dictionary literal syntax?

Comment: I've got an error like "collection object of type BOOL is not an objective-c object" when i try this method about "publicAccess" in line  NSDictionary * newDictionary = @{@"id" :mArray,@"publicAccess" : publicAccess};

Comment: is it ok for ur requirement.if ok.pls do the tickmark